# Change the fontsize of a button's label in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can someone help me change the fontsize of a button's label in actionscript 3? 
I have a button called "submit" from the components and I was able to change its
font using the "setStyle"...But I don't know how to change its fontsize. Is there 
a code similar to what I have just made? Below is the code on how I change the fontstyle. Any 
help will be very much appreciated..

```
submit.label = "Submit";
submit.setStyle("textFormat", new TextFormat("Impact"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter in the `TextFormat` constructor is for the font-size:

```
submit.setStyle("textFormat", new TextFormat("Impact", 24));  //would give a font size of 24 pixels
```

See the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html#TextFormat()) for other parameters such as text alignment, bold, underline etc..